# g++ optimizes out nullpointer checks

Tags: gcc, optimization, crash, g++

I have a function that is working if I compile with O0 flag but crashes on a function called on a nullptr if compiled with O2.

If I add some macros to disable optimizations around that function it will work properly.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlQbt.png

```
if (LPPARTY pkParty = GetParty())
    {
        struct FPartyBuff
        {
            const CSkillProto* pkSk;
            DWORD casterPID;
            int iAmount1, iDur1;
            int iAmount2, iDur2;

            FPartyBuff(const CSkillProto* pkSkill, DWORD caster, int amount1, int dur1, int amount2, int dur2)
                : pkSk(pkSkill), casterPID(caster), iAmount1(amount1), iDur1(dur1), iAmount2(amount2), iDur2(dur2) {}

            void operator() (LPCHARACTER ch)
            {
                bool bOverride = true;

                if (ch && ch->GetPlayerID() != casterPID)
                {
                    if (pkSk->bPointOn != POINT_NONE)
                    {
                        ch->AddAffect(pkSk->dwVnum, pkSk->bPointOn, iAmount1, pkSk->dwAffectFlag, iDur1, 0, bOverride, false, casterPID);
                        bOverride = false;
                    }

                    if (pkSk->bPointOn2 != POINT_NONE)
                    {
                        ch->AddAffect(pkSk->dwVnum, pkSk->bPointOn2, iAmount2, pkSk->dwAffectFlag, iDur2, 0, bOverride, false, casterPID);
                        bOverride = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if (pkVictim && pkParty->IsMember(pkVictim->GetPlayerID()))
        {
            FPartyBuff f(pkSk, GetPlayerID(), iAmount, iDur, iAmount2, iDur2);
            pkParty->ForEachNearMember(f);
        }
    }
```

But without them this part of the code calls IsMember on pkParty even when it is a nullpointer.
LPPARTY is defined as CParty*

Why is it happening?

Comment: Where do you test that pkParty is not null? Debugging code samples is impossible, try to reduce to a [mcve], and probably you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: this is how the sample starts: if (LPPARTY pkParty = GetParty())

Comment: Ah, right. It is possible that gcc inlines GetParty and sees things there that convince it that pkParty cannot be 0.